# Special Case of Composite mersenne number mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We want to investigate if a composite mersenne number $p|2^{qb}-1$ where $p\nmid2^q-1$ ,$q,p$ are primes, $p=1+6qb,\ qb\equiv1(mod64) $ and $b$ is an odd number.

In general for 
$$\begin{align*}
x^n\equiv1&\pmod p\\\
\end{align*}$$

The distinct solutions are
$$
g^{j(p-1)/d},\ \text{for}\ j=0,1,2\ldots,d-1.
$$
where $d=\gcd(n,p-1)$ and there are $d$ solutions.

Applying this to our special case $x=2^q,n=b \  $we get the number of solutions as $d=\gcd(n,p-1)=gcd(b,6qb)=b$ and the solutions are 
$$
g^{j6q},\ \text{for}\ j=1,2\ldots,b-1.
$$
Finally we get $2^q\equiv\ g^{j6q}(mod \ 1+6qb)\\$

This is how far we got can anybody help?
Note: We know If $p|2^{qb}-1$ then $p^2|2^{qb}-1$, so $p^2|(2^{qb}-1)/(2^{q}-1)$